# Google benchmark returning more time of int divison from double

Tags: c++, google-benchmark

I am new to google benchmark tool, I am testing all the operation timings.Please find my code as below.In this code i am testing how much time each operation (add / sub /mul /div) will take on my hardware.

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>


double min(double)
{
  return 2.2;
}

double max(double)
{
  return 8.8;
}

int min(int)
{
  return 2;
}

int max(int)
{
  return 8;
}

template <typename Data>
void bench_mark_mul(benchmark::State &state)
{
  Data a, b;
  a = min(a);
  b = max(b);

  while (state.KeepRunning())
  {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a * b);
  }
}

template <typename Data>
void bench_mark_div(benchmark::State &state)
{
  Data a, b;
  a = min(a);
  b = max(b);

  while (state.KeepRunning())
  {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a / b);
  }
}

template <typename Data>
void bench_mark_sum(benchmark::State &state)
{
  Data a, b;
  a = min(a);
  b = max(b);

  while (state.KeepRunning())
  {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a + b);
  }
}

template <typename Data>
void bench_mark_dif(benchmark::State &state)
{
  Data a, b;
  a = min(a);
  b = max(b);

  while (state.KeepRunning())
  {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a - b);
  }
}

BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE1(bench_mark_dif, double);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE1(bench_mark_sum, double);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE1(bench_mark_mul, double);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE1(bench_mark_div, double);

BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE1(bench_mark_dif, int);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE1(bench_mark_sum, int);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE1(bench_mark_mul, int);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE1(bench_mark_div, int);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

**i am getting below results.**

[image]

Why double division time less then int division ?
As i am making conclusion its due to conversion from float to int when we are dividing 
the number?